# Using draggable google.maps.Marker with angular.js TypeError: a.lat is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api-3

The given code will add a google.maps.Marker to the centered map. After a timeout of one second, when marker.setDraggable(true) was called, the marker is gone and the error **Uncaught TypeError: a.lat is not a function** was thrown in console.

If *{draggable: true}* is set directly as attribute of the marker, the error will occur and the marker won't show up, too. The same happens for the "animation" attribute.

This code was working two months ago.

Any suggestions?

```
    $scope.$on('mapInitialized', function (event, map) {
        $scope.map = map;

        map.setOptions({
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            minZoom: 3
        });

        _initializeMapMarker();

    });

    var _initializeMapMarker = function () {

        var buildingPos = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat($scope.vm.Latitude), parseFloat($scope.vm.Longitude));

        $scope.map.setCenter(buildingPos);

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: $scope.map,
            //draggable: true, // <----------   Uncaught TypeError: a.lat is not a function
            //animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP, // <----------   Uncaught TypeError: a.lat is not a function
            position: buildingPos
        });


        setTimeout(function () {
            marker.setDraggable(true); // <----------   Uncaught TypeError: a.lat is not a function
        },1000);
    }
```

Comment: Add a `console.log($scope.vm.Latitude)` right before `var buildingPos`. My guess is that `Latitude` or `Longitude` is undefined.

Comment: I allready checked all the vars. The location is correct. $scope.map.setCenter(buildingPos); centers Map at the given position and the marker is at the correct position, too.